# Different result of counting number between 1 and 2000 which the sum of all the digits is 25.

Tags: combinatorics

How many number between 1 and 2000 which the sum of all the digits is 25?

I have tried to answer in two ways.

**First way**

Let the digits is $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.

$A+B+C+D=25$ with $A\leq 1$, $B\leq 9$, $C\leq 9$, and $D\leq 9$.

I am using transformation $E=1-A$, $F=9-B$,  $G=9-C$, $H=9-D$. We have new equation
$$E+F+G+H=28-25=3,$$
with $E\geq 0$, $F\geq 0$, $G\geq 0$, and $H\geq 0$.

So, we have the number between 1 and 2000 which the sum of all the digits is 25 is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4+3-1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
6\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
=
20 \text{ numbers}.
$$

**Second way**

Compute 3 digits number which the sum is 25.

Let $A=0$.

$B+C+D=25$ with $B\leq 9$, $C\leq 9$, and $D\leq 9$

I am using transformation $F=9-B$,  $G=9-C$, $H=9-D$. We have new equation
$$F+G+H=27-25=2,$$
with $F\geq 0$, $G\geq 0$, and $H\geq 0$.

So, we have the number 3 digits which the sum of all the digits is 25 is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3+2-1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
=
6\text{ numbers}.
$$

Let $A=1$.

$1+B+C+D=25\iff B+C+D=24$ with $B\leq 9$, $C\leq 9$, and $D\leq 9$

I am using transformation $F=9-B$,  $G=9-C$, $H=9-D$. We have new equation
$$F+G+H=27-24=3$$
with $F\geq 0$, $G\geq 0$, and $H\geq 0$.

So, we have the number 4 digits (1000-1999) which the sum of all the digits is 25 is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3+3-1\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
=
10\text{ numbers}.
$$

So, we have the number between 1 and 2000 which the sum of all digits is 25 is
$$6+10=16\text{ numbers}.$$

**My question**

Why the result first way and second way is different?

I try to make list:
1996, 1987, 1978, 1969, 1897, 1888, 1879, 1798, 1789, 1699, 997, 988, 979, 898, 889, 799. There are 16 numbers.

Is the first way wrong?

Comment: It is easy to check that your list of 16 is correct, so the first method must be wrong. What is the reason for ${4+3-1\choose3}$?

Comment: Because the result of transformation.

Comment: I don't understand, how you count.  Can you explain it? Why do you use this transformation? Why do you use this formula ${4+3-1\choose3}$?

Comment: Because $A\leq 1$, to get new variable $E\geq 0$ let $E=1-A$. This also for $B, C, D\leq 9$, to get new variable $F, G, H\geq 0$ we must have transformation $F, G, H=9-B, 9-C, 9-D$. I use that formula, because it is combination with repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is incorrect.

Every combination of $A,B,C,D$ maps to a valid combination of $E,F,G,H$, such as $A=0, E=1$ and $A=1, E=0$. However, every combination of $E,F,G,H$ does not map to a combination of $A,B,C,D$: for example, $(E,F,G,H)=(3,0,0,0)$ leads to $A = -2$.

This means that you are counting solutions that are not valid in the original problem. In other words, you are overcounting in the first method.

In fact, there are four overcountings because when $E=3$, there is only one possibility for $F, G,H$, and when $E=2$ one of $F,G,H$ can be equal to $1$. When $E=1$ there is no issue. Thus there are four cases where you overcount.